# Restarting count column when different row appears in Python/Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, function, count, series

I have the following Pandas DataFrame with multiple amounts for each address. The count of 'amounts' per address varies.

```
Index                                           type    amount
0   0xd81c0B4FEA284c908C5700187a67698b416a6bcc  outflow 2.553800e+04
1   0xd81c0B4FEA284c908C5700187a67698b416a6bcc  inflow  1.999650e+05
2   0xd81c0B4FEA284c908C5700187a67698b416a6bcc  inflow  3.896400e+04
3   0x0A5E7C50eA6BB695F2f4e75D97D3381592B59C9F  inflow  3.060000e+05
4   0x2Eec494429E253938A10b2A9eCAD8ee7F603e4Af  outflow 1.569367e+05
5   0x2Eec494429E253938A10b2A9eCAD8ee7F603e4Af  outflow 1.219739e+04
```

I want to create a column that would count from 1 to n rows per address, but I don't know how to restart the count at the next address.

Something that would look like this:

```
Index                                           type    amount          Epoch
0   0xd81c0B4FEA284c908C5700187a67698b416a6bcc  outflow 2.553800e+04    1
1   0xd81c0B4FEA284c908C5700187a67698b416a6bcc  inflow  1.999650e+05    2
2   0xd81c0B4FEA284c908C5700187a67698b416a6bcc  inflow  3.896400e+04    3
3   0x0A5E7C50eA6BB695F2f4e75D97D3381592B59C9F  inflow  3.060000e+05    1
4   0x2Eec494429E253938A10b2A9eCAD8ee7F603e4Af  outflow 1.569367e+05    1
5   0x2Eec494429E253938A10b2A9eCAD8ee7F603e4Af  outflow 1.219739e+04    2
```

As you can see, the count of epochs restarts when a row with a new address appears.

How can I create a logic for that column for any given number of addresses/rows?

Additionally: is there anything I should watch out for when structuring the DataFrame? E.G., always grouping equal addresses and not having them appear in random places in the DataFrame.

Comment: Should the count ever continue for an address that shows up later, or should it always start over at 1?

Comment: Yes, it should keep track of the order of the address, going down the rows, although that would probably never happen.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `groupby` with `cumcount`:

1. If you want the count to continue if an address re-occurs later:

```
df["Epoch"] = df.groupby("Index").cumcount()+1

>>> df
                                        Index     type     amount  Epoch
0  0xd81c0B4FEA284c908C5700187a67698b416a6bcc  outflow   25538.00      1
1  0xd81c0B4FEA284c908C5700187a67698b416a6bcc   inflow  199965.00      2
2  0xd81c0B4FEA284c908C5700187a67698b416a6bcc   inflow   38964.00      3
3  0x0A5E7C50eA6BB695F2f4e75D97D3381592B59C9F   inflow  306000.00      1
4  0x2Eec494429E253938A10b2A9eCAD8ee7F603e4Af  outflow  156936.70      1
5  0x2Eec494429E253938A10b2A9eCAD8ee7F603e4Af  outflow   12197.39      2
6  0xd81c0B4FEA284c908C5700187a67698b416a6bcc   inflow  199965.00      4
7  0xd81c0B4FEA284c908C5700187a67698b416a6bcc   inflow   38964.00      5
```

2. If you want the count to re-start at 1 for the address that re-occurs:

```
df["Epoch"] = df.groupby((df["Index"]!=df["Index"].shift()).cumsum()).cumcount()+1

>>> df
                                        Index     type     amount  Epoch
0  0xd81c0B4FEA284c908C5700187a67698b416a6bcc  outflow   25538.00      1
1  0xd81c0B4FEA284c908C5700187a67698b416a6bcc   inflow  199965.00      2
2  0xd81c0B4FEA284c908C5700187a67698b416a6bcc   inflow   38964.00      3
3  0x0A5E7C50eA6BB695F2f4e75D97D3381592B59C9F   inflow  306000.00      1
4  0x2Eec494429E253938A10b2A9eCAD8ee7F603e4Af  outflow  156936.70      1
5  0x2Eec494429E253938A10b2A9eCAD8ee7F603e4Af  outflow   12197.39      2
6  0xd81c0B4FEA284c908C5700187a67698b416a6bcc   inflow  199965.00      1
7  0xd81c0B4FEA284c908C5700187a67698b416a6bcc   inflow   38964.00      2
```

Note the difference in output in the last two rows. I copied the second and third rows of your example to the end of the DataFrame to illustrate the difference in the two methods.